# Spark Kryo Exception - Class is not registered: com.google.common.base.Present

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, guava, kryo

I am using Spark 1.6.0-cdh5.8.0.

I'm trying to use Kryo.  I have guava Optional because I thought that's what spark was using.

However I cannot serialize that using Kryo because Present class has default-visibility.

So...has anyone come across this and solved it.

The following code does not work since Present is hidden...

```
kryo.register(com.google.common.base.Present.class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
kryo.register(Class.forName("com.google.common.base.Present"))
```